# How To Create Reusable Window Template/Model - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, window

Ok, I'll try to explain what I want to accomplish:

I'm quite new to WPF and XAML and I would like to create some domestic use applications with **custom reusable UI**. To be clear, I would like that every `Window` uses the same "Appearence" (specially the non-client area) without customizing every single one of them.
I've done some researches (obviously) and I found something that resembles perfectly what I'm trying to do: [MahApps.Metro](http://mahapps.com/) Template.
But I don't want to use some third party code because I like to have control all over my application and I want to customize what I want by myself. So I'd like to know what is the correct (and the best, maybe) way to do so. I've read plenty of posts about `Window` customizing but I didn't find anything that explained how to do that in **that** way.

I hope to have well-explained myself and I thank you all in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make custom UI in XAML you should learn to use Expression Blend. Here is a resource you can try -

- [Inspirational Textbox Styles (Source code available)](http://www.blendrocks.com/code-blend/2015/2/11/inspirational-textbox-styles-for-windows-phone-and-store)

There are several videos available on youtube on Expression Blend for making custom UI in XAML. You can try that.